# Do I need to update Oracle Client?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, odbc, client

How does Oracle maintain Oracle Client software? I don't find [Patch Updates](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/security/alerts-086861.html) for the Client Software of Oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client-only installation is similar to a database server installation, but it has a reduced set of components. It can be patched with the database PSU/RU.

E.g. this is from the readme of the 11.2.0.4.180417 database PSU (11g, because the latest 12c readme does not have a similar section):

> For each installation type, it indicates the most recent PSU patch to
>   include new security fixes that are pertinent to that installation
>   type. If there are no security fixes to be applied to an installation
>   type, then "None" is indicated. If a specific PSU is listed, then
>   apply that or any later PSU patch to be current with security fixes.

[image]

Instant Client installations can not be patched with the same method, for that see: [How to Apply a Patch to an Oracle Instant Client Installation? (Doc ID 1072125.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=1072125.1)

> To patch an Oracle Instant Client installation:
>
> 1. You would need a full client installation of the same version.
> 2. Apply the patch to the full client installation, regenerate the instant client shared libraries.
> 3. Copy the libraries to the Instant client.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the database server updates include client updates.

See this CPU:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/security-advisory/cpuapr2017-3236618.html#AppendixDB

Includes a fix to SQL*Plus which is part of the client.

Bobby